# html2canvas saving as a jpeg without opening in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

I am trying to create a screengrab button that creates an image of the user's `document.body`.

Ideally the user would then have an option to save the image locally as a `.jpeg`.

I am getting close to creating the functionality I need using the [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library.

```
function screenGrabber() {
    html2canvas([document.body], {
    logging: true,
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function (canvas) {            

        img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");

        console.log(img.length);
        console.log(img);

        window.location.href=img; // it will save locally
    }
});

}
```

To verify that this is working I've been opening the `img` variable in a new browser window. The image does not render completely and I am guessing that's because it's length is over 30,000 characters.

How might I better give the user an option to save the canvas locally after the `onrendered` event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a downloader function makes it much easier:

```
function download(strData, strFileName, strMimeType) {
    var D = document,
        A = arguments,
        a = D.createElement("a"),
        d = A[0],
        n = A[1],
        t = A[2] || "text/plain";

    //build download link:
    a.href = "data:" + strMimeType + "," + escape(strData);


    if (window.MSBlobBuilder) {
        var bb = new MSBlobBuilder();
        bb.append(strData);
        return navigator.msSaveBlob(bb, strFileName);
    } /* end if(window.MSBlobBuilder) */



    if ('download' in a) {
        a.setAttribute("download", n);
        a.innerHTML = "downloading...";
        D.body.appendChild(a);
        setTimeout(function() {
            var e = D.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(e);
            D.body.removeChild(a);
        }, 66);
        return true;
    } /* end if('download' in a) */
    ; //end if a[download]?

    //do iframe dataURL download:
    var f = D.createElement("iframe");
    D.body.appendChild(f);
    f.src = "data:" + (A[2] ? A[2] : "application/octet-stream") + (window.btoa ? ";base64" : "") + "," + (window.btoa ? window.btoa : escape)(strData);
    setTimeout(function() {
        D.body.removeChild(f);
    }, 333);
    return true;
} /* end download() */





function screenGrabber() {
    html2canvas([document.body], {
    logging: true,
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function (canvas) {            

        img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

       download(img, "modified.jpg", "image/jpeg");
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Hey Dandavis. Could you post a jsfiddle of this example?

Comment: Good example, despite not having tested, theoretically seems quite functional. +1

Comment: I assume ```MSBlobBuilder``` is eligible only for IE, is there any cross-platform way to do this?

Comment: @SviatoslavZalishchuk: cross-platform way to do what? (MSBlobBuilder is only used by IE9+10), but it's a small part of the compat stack used. refer to https://github.com/rndme/download for updates