# How to force a download instead of opening the file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

So basically, I am using a simple library called `HTML2Canvas`

This is my current code working great and is being called from an `onclick` event from a button:

```
function saveForm()
{
    html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            }
        });
}
```

Basically, all it does is take a screen shot and append it to the bottom of the page.

There was already a question similar to this, although the answer did not work and the download is always a corrupt jpg file:
[html2canvas saving as a jpeg without opening in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429214/html2canvas-saving-as-a-jpeg-without-opening-in-browser)

Would there be a way to force a download within this function instead of appending it to the bottom of the page?

Comment: What would it download? A canvas is not a file.

Comment: @Juhana - Very true, although I could take advantage of `toDataURL` like so - `img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `canvas.toDataURL` to get the canvas content as an image src
2. open a window/popup
3. add an `<img>` to the popup
4. assign the image src as `src` for the image

---

```
function saveForm() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var open = window.open('','','width=500,height=500')
            open.document.write('<img id="img" style="width="400">');
            open.document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('src', img);
        }
    });
}
```

Tested the code inside `onrendered`, and it works for sure - but not along with html2canvas.

If you right click on the image in the popup -> save image as, the saved image is valid.

The reason why I am using `setAttribute` and not simply `src="..."` is that if you assign the data src as string the image get corrupted.

---

**Edit**
I know :( I think you have to set HTTP Headers to force a download, and this can only be done by the server (correct me if I am wrong). I think of a "proxy" on the server like this mockup, download.php :

```
<?
$src=$_POST['src'];
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="download.png"');
header('Content-Length: '.count($src));
echo $src;
?>
```

and call it by

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
window.open('download.php?src='+img);
```

But then you will face a lot of `Request-URI Too Large`-messages, unless all your canvas-images is in icon-size.

A second way - and probably the one that would work - would be to save `img` in a table on the server through ajax, eg calling a script with img src that saves it. When this call is finished, you could call another server script with the correct headers for image download, including the img src saved just before. But this is a more extensive approach you could try yourself..?

Comment: Hey, great code. Although, I already knew how to open it in a new window. I was asking to see if it was possible to have a button that allows them to download the image straight away.

Comment: Ahhhh right, very tricky haha. Do you have any idea why that other script does not work that I posted a link to within my question? It seems to force the download perfectly in a `jpg` file, although when I try and open the file it states that it is invalid...

Comment: @fzzk, no I dont know html2canvas, sorry. But I think it could be easy to make one for your own. Make a canvas at papersize and run trough the DOM, copy the content to canvas with same metrics as the metrics on the screen. It is not as hard as it sounds. If it was, those behind html2canvas were billionares :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that builds on the accepted one to enable a download button without server-side code using jQuery.

https://codepen.io/nathansouza/pen/OXdJbo

```
function download(url){
  var a = $("<a style='display:none' id='js-downloder'>")
  .attr("href", url)
  .attr("download", "test.png")
  .appendTo("body");

  a[0].click();

  a.remove();
}

function saveCapture(element) {
  html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {
    download(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
  })
}

$('#btnDownload').click(function(){
  var element = document.querySelector("#capture");
  saveCapture(element)
})
```