# html2canvas js returns uncaught (in promise) undefined

Tags: javascript

This question has been asked here but no adequate answer was given:
[html2canvas Uncaught (in promise) undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767557/html2canvas-uncaught-in-promise-undefined)

Uncaught (in promise) also has been asked a lot but none of those seem to give me the answer.  Apparently I'm catching the error incorrectly.

Here I am placing more code than that question as to define the problem more.

I am attempting to take a screen shot with the following code:

```
        function take_screenshot()
        {
          html2canvas(document.querySelector("#img_preview_text_container")).then(canvas => {
              var img = canvas.toDataURL()
              console.log('I took screenshot');
              $.post("save_screenshot.php", {data: img}, function (file){
                window.location.href =  "save_screenshot.php?file="+ file
              });
          });
        }
```

This produces the following error: 
Uncaught (in promise) undefined.  According to several so answers I should catch the error by doing this:

```
function take_screenshot()
{
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#img_preview_text_container"))
  .then(canvas => {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL()
      console.log('I took screenshot');
      $.post("save_screenshot.php", {data: img}, function (file){
        window.location.href =  "save_screenshot.php?file="+ file
      })
    .catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    };
  });
}
```

catch e here does not affect the results, I still get 
Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429214/html2canvas-saving-as-a-jpeg-without-opening-in-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429214/html2canvas-saving-as-a-jpeg-without-opening-in-browser)

Comment: It gives no answer to the undefined promise @Miller Cy Chan

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091863/html2canvas-code-not-working-ie-11